# How to package the latest prebid successfully? version:1.117.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, maven-plugin, prebid

When I was in version 1.115.0-SNAPSHOT, I was able to run successfully。
But the latest version，execute 'mvn clean package -U -Dmaven.test.skip=true':

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.xolstice.maven.plugins:protobuf-maven-plugin:0.6.1:compile (default) on project prebid-server: Unable to resolve artifact: Missing:
> [ERROR] ----------
> [ERROR] 1) com.google.protobuf:protoc:exe:osx-aarch_64:3.17.0
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR]   Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR]   Then, install it using the command:
> [ERROR]       mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.google.protobuf -DartifactId=protoc -Dversion=3.17.0 -Dclassifier=osx-aarch_64 -Dpackaging=exe -Dfile=/path/to/file
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR]   Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
> [ERROR]       mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.google.protobuf -DartifactId=protoc -Dversion=3.17.0 -Dclassifier=osx-aarch_64 -Dpackaging=exe -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR]   Path to dependency:
> [ERROR]     1) org.prebid:prebid-server:jar:1.117.0-SNAPSHOT
> [ERROR]     2) com.google.protobuf:protoc:exe:osx-aarch_64:3.17.0
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] ----------
> [ERROR] 1 required artifact is missing.
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] for artifact:
> [ERROR]   org.prebid:prebid-server:jar:1.117.0-SNAPSHOT
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
> [ERROR]   central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)

I looked up most of the same reasons for the error, but it didn't seem to solve my problem.
Are there people who use prebid? Can you compile the latest version successfully？